# CSS box layout not playing nicely

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to design a css and html website but I am having some issues making it responsive. http://finfeeder.x10host.com/

Below are the pictures of what I'd like it to look like when on mobile and desktop.

Essentially, As the monitor gets smaller and smaller, the pictures should get smaller and stay in the same place until it becomes and certain size to completely change for mobile devices. Instead, it just gets smaller and more misaligned...

At the heart of it I know I don't understand how CSS layouts work but W3schools just didn't get the point across for my dumb self.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div.main {
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
}

div.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    left: 330px;
    top: 550px;
    z-index: 0;   
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
  <img src='https://xo2.x10hosting.com:2083/cpsess6981183432/viewer/home%2ffinfeede%2fpublic_html%2fimages/desktop_betta.jpg' style='width:100%' alt='[]' />
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<a href="http://facebook.com">
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/dhFsqcW.gif' style='width:15%' style='height:15%' />
</a>
<a href="http://pinterest.com">
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/qatEe7q.gif' style='width:15%' style='height:15%' />
</a>
<a href="http://instagram.com">
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/IoRiRiD.gif' style='width:15%' style='height:15%' />
</a>
<a href="http://twitter.com">
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/eqsUM0m.gif' style='width:15%' style='height:15%' />
</a>
<a href="http://kickstarter.com">
<img src='https://xo2.x10hosting.com:2083/cpsess6981183432/viewer/home%2ffinfeede%2fpublic_html%2fimages/kickbutton.gif' style='width:100%' alt='[]' />
</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please see my reply for links to what website should look like.
Thank ya kindly!

Comment: This is the desktop design .    https://xo2.x10hosting.com:2083/cpsess6981183432/viewer/home%2ffinfeede%2fpublic_html%2fimages/betta-splash-red-and-bluefull.jpg

Comment: This is the mobile design.  https://xo2.x10hosting.com:2083/cpsess6981183432/viewer/home%2ffinfeede%2fpublic_html%2fimages/betta-splash-red-and-blue-MOBILE.jpg

Comment: those links redirect to a login page.

Comment: crackers....lemme try to fix

Comment: You're not resizing your images, and absolute positioning isn't going to help you with mobile design unless you know exactly what you're doing. Look at code school or Google mobile design for help

Comment: THIS is the desktop design http://finfeeder.x10host.com/images/betta-splash-red-and-bluefull.jpg

Comment: THIS is the mobile site http://finfeeder.x10host.com/images/betta-splash-red-and-blue-MOBILE.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the div itself is designated with a hard-coded absolute position. If you change that to a percentage, it will stay in the same part of the screen regardless of how narrow the screen is.

You may also potentially use `max-width` and `min-width` properties to prevent elements from getting too small or large.

You should also make sure to define the width and height of your html and body as `100%` of the viewport. This way and elements with in it will inherit the correct width and height.

```
<style>

html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

div.main {
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height: 30%; /* This could also be coded with a px, pt, etc */
}

div.buttons {
position: absolute;
left: 5%;
top: 5%;
width: 90%;
z-index: 0;   
}

</style>
```

Since the `html`, `body` and `div.main` are all 100% the width of the viewport, positioning the div.buttons to be 5% from the left and setting it's width to 90% positions it to have 5% of space on either side, no matter how big or small the viewport is.

It's generally good practice to define things like height and width even if you don't think you need to because at some point another element may inherit that property, or be positioned relative to it.

If you use Google's Chrome browser you can enable the developers tools with `control` + `shift` + `i` and preview how your page with look on a variety of devices.

Comment: Thank you sir! Your comments really helped. My links aren't working anymore though for some reason.

Comment: Nevermind, found the issue was my links are now in the .main div so they inhereted the z-index of the main or something. Put the picture of the fish in it's own div with z index-1 and it solved it. YAY!